# Must be OpenGL?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

I'm new to android and I need to do a project like this : I have 22 images that represent a person which is rotating. When the user touch the right side of an other image the image is changing (the person is rotating to right). The same thing is for left side. 
  My question is: I must use OpenGL? I made some example with openGL but I don't see if for my project it is necessary. I was thinking that maybe it is enough to change the background image at every touch.

What do you guide me to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly the same thing but this tutorial by the excellent guys at Sony Ericsson show how to make a nice looking 3D list without OpenGL - http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/

Maybe you could use some of the techniques in this tutorial to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL may be useful to do your project

you can see the Example Code project here [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android/)

And The Blog url that has explained nicely to work with [OpenGL has many part of the Tutorial](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/)

May be looking at this you can get idea how to go ahead.